# Resizing numpy ndarray with linear interpolation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

Say I want to resize an array of shape (100,100,100) into an array of shape (57,57,57) using linear interpolation.

Basically I need a functiona that takes a n-dim array with shape S, and transforms it without complaining into an array with the same number of dimensions but with a different shape S' using interpolation.

Is there a simple and fast way to do this with numpy and scipy?
I found things like 1d interpolation, 2d interpolation, grid interpolation, but they require linear spaces and whatnot I don't really understand.

Comment: "linear interpolation" doesn't fully define how to go about the interpolation in more than one dimensions. You probably have [trilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation) in mind (which is not linear), but any truly linear interpolation requires defining a tetrahedral tessellation of your cube before proceeding.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method griddata from scipy.interpolate

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
```

Lets say your 3D array is given by:

```
array3d
```

You will need to reshape your data and create another array with the original indexes, or point coordinates

```
N=100
array3DAux = array3D.reshape(N**3)

# ijk is an (N**3,3) array with the indexes of the reshaped array.
ijk = mgrid[0:N,0:N,0:N].reshape(3,N**3).T
```

Now you can create the new grid that you want do find the new interpolated points.

```
#In your case 57 points
n = 57j
i,j,k = mgrid[0:N:n,0:N:n,0:N:n]
```

There are 3 interpolation methods nearest, linear and cubic
as follows

```
newArray3D_z0 = griddata(ijk,array3DAux,(i,j,k),method="nearest")
newArray3D_z1 = griddata(ijk,array3DAux,(i,j,k),method="linear")
newArray3D_z2 = griddata(ijk,array3DAux,(i,j,k),method="cubic")
```

In this case it will work to reduce or increase the size of your 3D array.

Hope it helps

Comment: This code fails for me on creating newArray with a ValueError: different number of values and points. ijk.shape is (3, 1000000) and array3DAux.shape is (1000000,)